# How to get number digit from the varchar 2 in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

I have variable l_string varchar 2(100).

The value of string is `l_string='L000EW45UY678IOP'`.

I want to get number from this string like

> 00045678

Please tell me how to get the above string result.

Answer (score 0):

Google the TRANSLATE function.

It will let you replace the alphabetic characters by nothing, leaving the digits behind.

Comment: to use the TRANSLATE function you'd probably have to list each character you want to eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
regexp_replace('L000EW45UY678IOP', '[^0-9]', '')
```